# Are there any limit to the total amount of moves in chess?

Tags: game-theory

Are there any limit to the total amount of possible moves before stalemate or checkmate in chess? If so, what is it and how do one prove that?

EDIT: As I wrote in a comment below,

> stalemate is the position when the player to move has no legal move and is not in check. According to the most common rules, draw also happens when the last fifty successive moves made by both players contain no capture or pawn move.

I hope this provides enough information in order to answer my question.

Comment: Define "Stalemate". There exist games with a loop at the end, but a mistake of either side could make that side lose.

Comment: I want to migrate this to Chess, but don't seem to get the option. Also see the analysis at http://www.chess.com/blog/kurtgodden/the-longest-possible-chess-game where there is some discussion of the effect of specific rules for ending the game too.

Comment: @MarkBennet It's more of a combinatorial question than one concerning the rules, moves and their implications in chess.

Comment: Not really, you can just move a few pieces back and forth ad infinitum

Comment: @MarkBennet Only websites past their beta phase show up in the migration possibilities.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks.

Comment: @AvZ I agree it is a counting question, but how and what to count depends on the rules. For example, whether the game automatically ends after threefold repetition or whether this has to be claimed by one of the players. If the first is the case all games are finite. And the counting depends crucially on the particular properties of pawns and their movement.

Comment: @MarkBennet Agreed, but questions like "Knight's tour","King's tour", et cetera are very much dependent on chess rules, but are distinctly mathematical questions.

Comment: @MarkBennet you can flag for moderators with reason "other" and propose to migrate. They could migrate it; I am not sure they will.

Comment: @quid I think there are enough people here to give an answer, but you there will be a better range of answers on chess, I think, dealing with variations in rules, as in the link I gave in a previous comment.

Comment: @AlexR Stalemate is the position when the player to move has no legal move and is not in check. According to the most common rules, draw also happens when the last fifty successive moves made by both players contain no capture or pawn move. I hope that this have clarified my terms.

Comment: @MarkBennet I tend to agree with you. The reason for adding my last half-sentence was not to disagree; merely I am unsure what would happen on a flag. //  Then http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8331/is-the-number-of-possible-chess-games-infinite seems like a near dupe on [chess.se]

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how you play... There is a 50-move rule in most tournament chess where either player can CLAIM a draw if 50 moves have happened without a pawn move or a capture. Granted, they don't have to claim the draw, so technically it could go on forever. If you impose that a game is automatically drawn if it violates the 50 move rule... then IIRC there is a maximum of 5948 moves.(To understand 5950, count how many captures and pawn moves can possibly happen... keeping in mind that certain pawn moves will ALSO have to be captures to allow for more pawn moves... it takes a bit more thinking to realize why you get two less than that.)

Comment: To put that in perspective tournament chess games rarely reach move 100. In the entire  history of master level chess not more than a handful games, if any, reached move 200

Comment: @AndreaMori Very true. According to wikipedia, the longest official tournament chess game was 269 moves. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_chess#Longest_game